# Как сделать так, чтобы commands работала только в определенных каналах

Tags: python, discord.py

Хочу сделать так, чтобы команда через @bot.command работала в определенных каналах, а не во всех на сервере. Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли так и сделать и если да, то как

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.id == 1008867763244249128:
        await ctx.send("TEST")
```

Где цифры - это ID необходимого канала.

Если этот ответ Вам помог, пожалуйста, не забудьте выбрать его, как ответ. Удачи в конструировании ботов!